# How to avoid column Index from PHP?

Tags: php, json

When I fetch all values from a table for creating a Json Formatted String I got Index also in the php response.How to avoid it?

My Php Program

```
<?php
include 'configa.php'; 
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message_store_push`") or die(mysql_error());
$c = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
$i=0;
while($sql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
         $arrDet['AddressDetails']['details'][] = $sql2;
}

 if($c>0){
    $arrDet['Details']['status'] = "success";
 } else {
    $arrDet['Details']['status'] = "No data";
 }
echo json_encode($arrDet);
?>
```

And Respose is

```
{
"AddressDetails":{
"details":[
{
"0":"1",
"key_id":"1",
"1":"2016-01-27 04:20:52",
"key_time":"2016-01-27 04:20:52",
"2":"HI",
"key_message":"HI"
}
]
},
"Details":{
"status":"success"
}
}
```

But I need

```
{
"AddressDetails":{
"details":[
{
"key_id":"1",
"key_time":"2016-01-27 04:20:52",
"key_message":"HI"
}
]
},
"Details":{
"status":"success"
}
}
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed in PHP 7.x. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this  :

```
<?php
include 'configa.php'; 
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message_store_push`") or die(mysql_error());
$c = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
$i=0;
while($sql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){ // instead of mysql_fetch_array()
         $arrDet['AddressDetails']['details'][] = $sql2;
}

 if($c>0){
    $arrDet['Details']['status'] = "success";
 } else {
    $arrDet['Details']['status'] = "No data";
 }
echo json_encode($arrDet);
?>
```

because mysql_fetch_array() returns the table value index and also  associative keys so to get only the associative keys and their values always use the mysql_fetch_assoc() function!!

Comment: Thanks this is really help

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

This

```
while($sql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
         $arrDet['AddressDetails']['details'][] = $sql2;
}
```

Should be

```
while($sql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
         $arrDet['AddressDetails']['details'][] = $sql2;
}
```

Also note mysql_* functions are removed from PHP 7, you may start using mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks this is really help